# ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor of shape [3,3,256,512] and type float

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Flatten,Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D
#from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import keras.optimizers
import gc
label=pd.read_csv('trainLabels.csv')
label=label.sort_values(by=['image'])
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),strides=(1,1),input_shape=(512,512,3),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,2),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4096,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='relu'))
opt = keras.optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt)
#ID=train_test_split(list(range(1000)),test_size=0.2,stratify=label['level'].iloc[0:1000])
df=np.array(df)
model.fit(df, label['level'].iloc[0:1000],epochs=100, batch_size=1)
gc.collect()
```

GPU:GTX980M-8GB
CPU: 2.7GHZ 8cores
Memeory: 16GB

```
df.shape
    Out[78]: (1000, 512, 512, 3)
```

error message:

```
ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor of shape [3,3,256,512] and type float
     [[Node: training_9/Adagrad/zeros_14 = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [3,3,256,512] values: [[[0 0 0]]]...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

The images are 512 X 512, and throughing a kind of standard vgg19
I am just asking is this problem caused by hardware drawbacks and can't be solved by any other methods? i.e. I can't processing 512 X 512 image via vgg19 using a 8GB GPU. I am kind of doubt that since there must be the same error using 11GB GPU while adding on the batch size. Or there should be something wrong or other solutions.

Comment: The problem seems that network is too big for that input size.  So it cannot allocate memory for given size/network. It could be the network fits well in 11GB GPU but not on 8GB GPU. Try removing several conv2D layers or reduce input image size (to 128x128 or 64x64) from your network and see if it works.

Comment: I tried 256 X 256 it did work, but it is highly possibily in trading of prediction acurracy. I am just kind of wondering that which kind of machine can do this kind of task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  don't think the model is too big to fit your GPU with 8GB memory.

In most cases, there is a process that use most of memory resources in GPU.

You can check which process consumes most of your GPU memory.

```
nvidia-smi
```

If you see something like `python` in `Process name`, just kill the process using `kill -9 [process ID]`

The process might be the model you executed, which is not killed and consumes most of GPU memory.